# Как использовать переменные связывания для литерала DATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, переменные, литерал

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob = DATE '1980-05-15'
```

Необходимо переписать запрос, чтобы избавиться от жестко кодированных значений и использовать вместо них переменные связывания. В итоге переписанный запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob = DATE :dateOfBirth
```

Однако этот запрос не работает:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Перепробовал все возможные форматы (`1980-05-15`, `15-MAY-80`, `15-MAY-1980`) для переменной `:dateOfBirth`, но безуспешно, всегда получаю одну и ту же ошибку.

---

**PS1:** Знаю о функции `to_date()`, которая может решить эту проблему, но я не могу ее использовать, потому что запрос формируется в другой системe, в которой нет возможности что-то изменить.

**PS2:** Формат даты `nls_date_format=DD-MON-RR` в БД, как указано в параметрах `nls_session_parameters` и `nls_database_parameters`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to use bind variables for date literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63780647) от участника [@cdoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34026/cdoe)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63780647

Answer (score 3):

**Правильное решение:**

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob = :dateOfBirth
```

**Причина ошибки:**

Литерал даты `DATE '1980-05-15'`это законченая синтаксическая конструкция, которую нельзя поделить на части, то есть она не может быть результатом выражения из нескольких операндов. Такое работать не будет:

```
select date ''||'1980-05-15' from dual
/
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

Парсер SQL, получая текст запроса, видит в этом фрагменте `DATE :dateOfBirth` два токена:

- `DATE`, после которго он ожидает символьный литерал, отсутствие которого и приводит к ошибке
- `:dateOfBirth`, переменные связывания он пропускает, что в них будет на этапе выполнения, ни тип данных, ни значение - ему неизвестно.

**Что должно быть в переменной связывания, раз литерал даты с ней не возможен?**

Определение и присвоение значения переменной связывания - задача клиентского приложения. Идеально использовать типы даты храняшие значение в бинарном виде. В любом ЯП есть соответствующие типы данных. Например, в JDBC переменная типа `java.time` будет передана в том же виде, в котором SQL `DATE` хранит своё значение:

```
select rawtohex (date'1980-05-15') hexvalue from dual
/
HEXVALUE
----------------
BC07050F00000000
```

Если по каким либо причинам возможен только символьный тип для переменной связывания, то *обязательно надо* изменить запрос на использование `to_date()` с *явным указанием формата*:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob = to_date (:dateOfBirth, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```